# Get field widget settings

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 7 they can be found in object that is returned by field_info_instance().
Is there a way to get widget settings for certain field name and bundle in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way :-)

```
$settings = entity_get_form_display('node', 'article', 'default')
  ->getComponent('field_image')['settings'];
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the new way, as entity_get_form_display is being deprecated, is this:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$bundle = 'page';
$form_mode = 'default';

$form_display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('entity_form_display')
  ->load($entity_type . '.' . $bundle . '.' . $form_mode);

$specific_widget_type = $form_display->getComponent('some_specific_field_machine_name');
if($specific_widget_type['type'] == 'some_widget_machine_name';

// ^ OR v

$widget_types = $form_display->getComponents();
foreach ($widget_types as $widget_type) {
  if ($widget_type['type'] == "some_widget_machine_name") {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Widget settings are part of entity form displays, not field settings

Comment: Correct, but could use some more information/example code :)

Answer (score 0):

Just shorter version how to get $form_display comparing to RaisinBranCrunch's

```
$form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewDisplay($entity_type, $bundle, $form_mode);
$form_display->getComponent('field_name')['settings'];
```

Comment: the first line give the view display, shouls be `$form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getFormDisplay($entity_type, $bundle, $form_mode);`